# Generic Arthur-parameter of symplectic group

Tags: automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

For a irreducible cuspidal automorphic representation $\pi$ of $Sp(2n)$, we can attach its generic $A$-parameter, that is isobaric sum automorphic representation of $GL_{2n+1}$.

I know it is of the form $\tau \oplus \chi$, where $\tau$ is a automorphic cuspidal representation of $GL_{2n}$ and $\chi$ is the central character of $\tau$.

I am wondering whether $\chi$ is a quadratic character. In some paper, it is seemingly true.

But I didn’t find the precise statement of this in Arthur’s book. Would you let me know some reference of it?